# Significance of Git add warning message 'The file will have its original line endings in your working directory'?

Tags: git

I have a project that I am migrating from ClearCase to Git. I have copied the code into my local GIT repository. Set gitignore to ignore .copyarea files. 
I used the following command to add the code under tracking:
**git add --all :/**

My bash fills up with message:
*The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in gfe/gfeadmin/src/main/admin/scripts/scripts/create-server-cache.sh.*

What does this mean?
What is the significance of this error message? Can I simply ignore this and proceed with committing to Git ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows and *nix (including Mac) use different characters to mark the end of a line.  Git will default to transparently converting between these line endings, and will produce that message to let you know what it's doing.

It's normal, default behavior and only occurs when a file is first added to git.  However, it can be configured to behave differently.  Normally you don't need to do this, but if you're interested you can research the `core.autocrlf` setting.